# Conditional Formating blank cells only based on other data

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am creating a workbook for completed training. I need to track who has completed training and whose training is overdue. I only want the formatting on blank cells.
So if an employee has to complete a certain training in 56 days I have been using this conditional formatting =today()>(startdate Cell+ 56) but I have to create a new rule for every blank cell.
I know I can adjust this with removing the $ but then it also formats the filled cells.
Is there a way to format the whole column, but leave the cells that are already filled alone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `startdate Cell` is `A1` and the range of cells you want to format is `A2:D6`:

Select `A2:D6` starting with `A2` (so it is white). Then add a new Conditional Formatting rule, and select "Use a formula...".

In the formula box enter `=and(isblank(A2),today()>($A$1+56))`

Comment: Thank you So Much!